# FMResultSet not work

Tags: iphone, database

every one.
I'm trying to use my custom database.
So I written following.
But If when i ran this, i found it return nil.

Why?

I didn't find why this is.

Please help me.

```
NSString *name ;
NSString * content ;
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT name, content FROM projects WHERE id = %d", projectID];
```

Here projectID is a given parameter.
And i had a breakpoint just next line.

```
//if ([rs next]) {
    name = [rs stringForColumnIndex:0];
    content = [rs stringForColumnIndex:1];
    [rs close];
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name, @"name", content, @"content", nil];
//}
[rs close];
return nil;
```

At the resutl, the name and content was nil. What happened?

Before that, db is opened correctly, and i updated it. I saw this by log and commandline of sqlite3 on terminal.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read documentation.

Correct way of passing parameters to query format is:

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT name, content FROM projects WHERE id = (?)", projectID];